# Broken pagination in the Winter Bash leaderboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard, winter-bash-2021

The pagination of the [Winter Bash leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) is broken:

[image: broken Winter Bash leaderboard]

It looks like there's an extra `s` to the `class` attribute (`classs`):

[image: classs misspell in devtools]

Using `class=` works:

[image: fixed pagination]

Comment: Well, at least this triple-tap typo didn't [cause the site to crash entirely](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Incident_documentation/20151005-MediaWiki)...

Comment: Classsic error.